# Curvature Formula

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $c:I\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular parametrized curve (not necessarily be arc length in general). Show that the curvature in the point $c(t)$ is

$\kappa(t)=\dfrac{\det(c'(t),c''(t))}{\|c'(t)\|^3}.$

Hello, how can show this? What result need?

Comment: What is your definition of "curvature"? What happens if you apply it?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Let $c:I\to \mathbb{R}^2$ parametrized curve by arc lenght. The curvature in $p=c(t)$ is defined at $c''(t)=\kappa(t)n(t)\iff \kappa(t)=\langle c''(t),n(t)\rangle.$

Comment: You might start by writing $c(t) = \bar{c}(\tau(t))$, in which $\bar{c}$ is parametrized by arc length, and therefore $\tau'(t) = \|c'(t)\|$ is the speed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand your notation, but if you look at a curve in the complex plane, say $z(t)$, then it can be shown that the curvature is given by

$$\kappa=\frac{\mathfrak{Im}\{\dot z^*\ddot z\}}{|\dot z|^3}$$

In Cartesian coordinates, if we allow that the curve is given by $y=f(x)$, then the curvature is given by

$$\kappa=\frac{|y''|}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}$$

Perhaps you will find this useful.

Comment: I am sorry but IMHO, this "answer" should at most be a "comment" .  Why ? Because 1) your first formula is **almost nowhere used**, 2) the connection (you use a "then") with the second formula is all but evident 3) That this second formula is at a yearlight from the formula given by the OP.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for you comment, I'll remember that in the future. However, regarding the first equation, I use it. In fact I use complex variables almost exclusively for planes curves, tessellations, fractal tilings, and more. It pains me to see teeth-gnashing that people suffer with Cartesian coordinates. And you're right, the second equation is a subset of that given by the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you that complex numbers are largely under-used for graphical purposes, although they are the key for very efficient representations.